# Tomcat manager ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I use Eclipse IDE and I've JBOSS and Tomcat installed: everything seems to works, but...
When I try to connect to `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` to use the administration panel, I get this error:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

this is my tomcat-users file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>


  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="mauro" password="mauro"
roles="manager-gui,manager-script "/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Windows firewall is disabled, and until now I've never had problems to see all my JPS

Answer (score 0):

Give role `manager-gui` to some user

```
<user username="manager" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

> NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role
>   required   to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you
>   wish to use this app,   you must define such a user - the username and
>   password are arbitrary.